# Need to use a column in a Select statement but does not want in Group By clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using this query to fetch certain load_ids:

```sql
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ldm.load_id) AS rn,
    CASE 
        WHEN pkd.status = 'STAGED' 
            THEN (ldm.load_id + '*') 
            ELSE ldm.load_id 
    END AS load_id
FROM
    t_load_master ldm
INNER JOIN 
    t_pick_detail pkd ON ldm.load_id = pkd.load_id
WHERE
    ldm.wh_id = '270'
    AND ldm.door_loc = 'DDR793'
    AND ldm.status != 'S'
    AND pkd.status IN ('STAGED', 'LOADED')
GROUP BY 
    pkd.load_id, ldm.load_id, pkd.status
HAVING 
    NOT (SUM(pkd.shipped_quantity) >= SUM(pkd.planned_quantity))
```

In simple words the query returns load_id with asterisk if its grouped status is 'STAGED' and without asterisk if its 'LOADED'.

This is the result I am getting:

[image]

As you can see I am getting `load_id = '5279380000'` twice because it has a few rows in 'LOADED' and a few in 'STAGED' status. I want to have only the one with the asterisk in the results.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Mention the correct RDMBS you are using it can't be mysql and sqlserver both at the same time.

Comment: Please avoid posting image. Post as formatted text

Comment: you can add a where clausule that checks against a subquery of the same dataset

Comment: The condition `NOT (SUM(pkd.shipped_quantity) >= SUM(pkd.planned_quantity))` Is it supposed to be by `load_id` + `status` or only `load_id` ?

Comment: @sqirrel only for load_id

Comment: @J.Salas can you explain how

Comment: *Consumable* sample data (not an image), expected results and a full explanation will help us help you here.

Comment: When you have "INNER JOIN t_pick_detail pkd ON **ldm.load_id = pkd.load_id**", why `GROUP BY pkd.load_id, ldm.load_id` ??  Those two id's should have same value always?

Answer (score 0):

If you want one line per id you need to use an agregrate function for the value of `staged`. As you want the higher value of `staged` ('STAGED' comes after 'LOADED' in an alphabetical sort) we can use `MAX()`.

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ldm.load_id) AS rn,
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(pkd.status) = 'STAGED' 
            THEN (ldm.load_id + '*') 
            ELSE ldm.load_id 
    END AS load_id
FROM
    t_load_master ldm
INNER JOIN 
    t_pick_detail pkd ON ldm.load_id = pkd.load_id
WHERE
    ldm.wh_id = '270'
    AND ldm.door_loc = 'DDR793'
    AND ldm.status != 'S'
    AND pkd.status IN ('STAGED', 'LOADED')
GROUP BY 
    pkd.load_id, ldm.load_id, pkd.status
HAVING 
    NOT (SUM(pkd.shipped_quantity) >= SUM(pkd.planned_quantity));
```